# Accessing an id loaded from another file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, datatables

### Update

I now have everythign in the load function, as suggested in the answers, but get a different error:

> `TypeError: table.column is not a function`

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>
<body>
  This report is updated every three minutes. The last update took place at $TIMESTAMP_UPDATE$.<br/>
  <div id="colvis" width="100%"></div>
  <table id="main_table"></table>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>

   $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#main_table');

        table.load("latest_flight.html", function() {
            table.DataTable( {
                "paging": true
            });

            $("#main_table thead th").each( function ( i ) {
            var name = table.column( i ).header();
            var spanelt = document.createElement( "button" );
            spanelt.innerHTML = name.innerHTML;                     

            $(spanelt).addClass("colvistoggle");
            $(spanelt).attr("colidx",i);        // store the column idx on the button

            $(spanelt).on( 'click', function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault(); 
                  // Get the column API object
                  var column = table.column( $(this).attr('colidx') );
                  // Toggle the visibility
                  column.visible( ! column.visible() );
            });
            $("#colvis").append($(spanelt));
            });

        });
   });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

---

### Original question:

Consider the following simple HTML file.  I am unable to iterate through the headers of the table that I am loading from a separate file. Why?

```
<html>
<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.dataTables/1.9.4/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div id="colvis"></div>
  <table id="main_table"></table>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.9/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
  <script>

   $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#main_table');

        table.load("file_with_table.html", function() {
            table.DataTable( {
                "paging": true
            });

        });

          // ============================================================================
          // THE FOLLOWING FAILS, #head DOES NOT HOLD thead's, is it because it's a div?
          //  ============================================================================
          // For each column in header add a togglevis button in the div
          $("#table thead th").each( function ( i ) {
                var name = table.column( i ).header();
                var spanelt = document.createElement( "button" );
                spanelt.innerHTML = name.innerHTML;                     

                $(spanelt).addClass("colvistoggle");
                $(spanelt).attr("colidx",i);        // store the column idx on the button

                $(spanelt).on( 'click', function (e) {
                      e.preventDefault(); 
                      // Get the column API object
                      var column = table.column( $(this).attr('colidx') );
                      // Toggle the visibility
                      column.visible( ! column.visible() );
                });
                $("#colvis").append($(spanelt));
          });

    });

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

where `file_with_table.html` holds:

```
<table border="1" class="dataframe" id="my_table">
  <thead>
    <tr style="text-align: right;">
      <th>school</th>
      <th>county</th>
      <th>zipcode</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>XX</td>
      <td>YY</td>
      <td>ZZ</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>XX</td>
      <td>YY</td>
      <td>ZZ</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Do you see it in the DOM Explorer?

Answer (score 3):

this is because the load is async, move the each statement inside the callback function of the load request.

```
   table.load("file_with_table.html", function() {
        table.DataTable( {
            "paging": true
        });

      $("#my_table thead th").each( function ( i ) {
            var name = table.column( i ).header();
            var spanelt = document.createElement( "button" );
            spanelt.innerHTML = name.innerHTML;                     

             $(spanelt).addClass("colvistoggle");
            $(spanelt).attr("colidx",i);        // store the column idx on the button

            $(spanelt).on( 'click', function (e) {
                  e.preventDefault(); 
                  // Get the column API object
                  var column = table.column( $(this).attr('colidx') );
                  // Toggle the visibility
                  column.visible( ! column.visible() );
            });
            $("#colvis").append($(spanelt));
      });

    });
```

Comment: Thanks @taxicala. I have updated the post. I am still getting an error accessing `column` in `table`.

Comment: I've editet my answer, your table has an id of #my_table and not #table.

Comment: Thanks! So I should use the `id` of the `table` that I have in `file_with_table.html` and not the `id` of the `div` I have in `index.html` where I load the table?

Comment: I believe yes since the table is loaded via ajax

Answer (score 2):

`.load()` uses AJAX, so it's asynchronous. Your loop is running immediately after you send the AJAX request, not waiting for it to fill in the DOM. You need to put the loop into the callback function.

```
table.load("file_with_table.html", function() {
    table.Datatable({
        paging: true
    });
    $("#my_table thead th").each(...);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Tried this in my project. Just remove the table element in your `file_with_table.html` and just set it as this:

```
<thead>
<tr style="text-align: right;">
  <th>school</th>
  <th>county</th>
  <th>zipcode</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
  <td>XX</td>
  <td>YY</td>
  <td>ZZ</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>XX</td>
  <td>YY</td>
  <td>ZZ</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

And try using this:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    // load the function
    LoadTable();


    // fill the table here
    function LoadTable() {

        $.post("file_with_table.html", function(data) {
            $('#main_table').html(data);
        });

    });
```

Removing the table in your `file_with_table.html` file is important because as i've known you cannot put a table within a table.
Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks wwwDELL. I followed your suggestion, and I am still getting an error accessing `column` in `table`.

Comment: can you please show us the error for us to be able to help you in some ways. Thanks.